# nexus status is Pending

Tags: acumos

When I deploy the Acumos used the command“bash oneclick_deploy.sh 2>&1 | tee aio_deploy.log”
it is not successful and print out “nexus status is Pending”

①I used an existing k8s cluster：Minikube

②the command"bash system-integration/AIO/setup_prereqs.sh k8s localhost $USER generic 2>&1 | tee aio_prep.log"
run successfully

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
master@ubuntu:/home$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
acumos        nexus-5b577d94f8-hqxxl                0/1     Pending   0          18m
kube-system   coredns-6967fb4995-p2sjh              1/1     Running   3          3d20h
kube-system   coredns-6967fb4995-p57ml              1/1     Running   3          3d20h
kube-system   etcd-minikube                         1/1     Running   0          5h14m
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube           1/1     Running   2          3d20h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube               1/1     Running   0          5h14m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube      1/1     Running   2          5h14m
kube-system   kube-proxy-2wqqp                      1/1     Running   1          3d20h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube               1/1     Running   2          3d20h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-95564f4f-wrjgj   1/1     Running   2          3d20h
kube-system   storage-provisioner                   1/1     Running   2          3d20h
kube-system   tiller-deploy-75f5747884-5rnmc        1/1     Running   0          5h8m
```

kubectl describe -n acumos pod nexus-5b577d94f8-hqxxl

```
master@ubuntu:/home$ kubectl describe -n acumos pod nexus-5b577d94f8-hqxxl
Name:           nexus-5b577d94f8-hqxxl
Namespace:      acumos
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=nexus
                pod-template-hash=5b577d94f8
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nexus-5b577d94f8
Containers:
  nexus:
    Image:       sonatype/nexus:3.9.0
    Ports:       8081/TCP, 8082/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Environment:
      log_level:  DEBUG
    Mounts:
      /maven/logs from logs (rw)
      /nexus-data from nexus-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-r6d6c (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  logs:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  logs
    ReadOnly:   false
  nexus-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  nexus-data
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-r6d6c:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-r6d6c
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  47s (x2 over 47s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

This problem has been bothering me for a long time and has not been solved.I would be grateful if someone could guide me on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please post the resources available: how much RAM, how many CPU cores.  If the machine is starved for RAM, the containers take an extremely long time to start, and the script may give up before the Nexus container becomes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you debug this but note that we have not tested these tools in minikube envs. Minikube is different enough from a single-node (AIO) k8s cluster that it's likely not to work; note also that you can create a single-node cluster (on Ubuntu or Centos) using the script https://github.com/acumos/system-integration/blob/master/tools/setup_k8s.sh.

But for your minikube case, the "pending" state for pods states typically mean that a PV is not ready to be allocated for a PVC. This may be a minikube side-effect. What is the result of "kubectl get pv" ?

Comment: The result of "kubectl get pv" is as follows. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Later, I'll try to use that script to create a single node cluster on ubuntu.
The result of "kubectl get pv"：

```
master@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs$ kubectl get pv
NAME                 CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
docker-volume        5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
elasticsearch-data   10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
logs                 1Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
mariadb-data         5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
nexus-data           10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
nifi-registry        5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-10gi-1            10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-10gi-2            10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-10gi-3            10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-10gi-4            10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-10gi-5            10Gi       RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-1gi-1             1Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-1gi-2             1Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-1gi-3             1Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-1gi-4             1Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-1gi-5             1Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-5gi-1             5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-5gi-2             5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-5gi-3             5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-5gi-4             5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
pv-5gi-5             5Gi        RWO            Recycle          Available                                   22h
```

kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces:

```
master@ubuntu:/home$ kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE   NAME         STATUS    VOLUME       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
acumos      logs         Pending   logs         0                         standard       27h
acumos      nexus-data   Pending   nexus-data   0                         standard       158m
```

Answer (score 0):

[I think resource allocation is enough.32G RAM and 16 CPU cores：](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSjmn.png)